# How to declare a new type from unions?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I find myself declaring a lot stuff as `Foo|Bar|Baz` and I'm getting tired of writing that. How can I `declare type Foob = Foo|Bar|Baz` so that I can start using `Foob` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exactly as you typed.

```
type Foo = {};
type Bar = {};
type Ba = {};
declare type Foob = Foo|Bar|Ba;
let x:Foob;
```

Comment: Aw man, I was just making that up. I didn't think it'd work verbatim!

Comment: The TypeScript design team's time machine has been paying great dividends lately